# Fetch data from 2 tables without cross join Parallel fetch

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to have a Oracle query .
I have 2 tables

1st table -- Receipt table

```
Receipt no  Amount Paid  Policy No  
1            100          101  
2            100          101  
3            100          101
```

2 nd  table -- Checks Table

```
Policy no Check No Check Amt  
101       1         150  
101       2         150
```

I need to have output like this clubbed from 2 tables

```
Policy No Receipt no Receipt Amount Check No Check Amount  
101        1         100            1         150  
101        2         100            2         150  
101        3         100
```

Reverse case is also possible.
I can 2 Receipt and multiple checks for the same policy
Please advice .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for an `OUTER JOIN` -- assuming you are joining on the Receipt and Check number fields:

```
SELECT R.PolicyNo, R.ReceiptNo, R.Amount, C.CheckNo, C.CheckAmt
FROM Receipt R
   LEFT JOIN Checks C ON R.ReceiptNo = C.CheckNo
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Perhaps you are also intending on joining on your PolicyNo field -- if so, just include that in the `JOIN`:

```
   LEFT JOIN Checks C ON R.ReceiptNo = C.CheckNo AND R.PolicyNo = C.PolicyNo
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not joining Receipt No & Check No. It is both different field.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT * FROM Receipt table 
FULL OUTER JOIN Checks Table
ON Receipt table  = Checks Table
```